# ruby metaprogramming better solution

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How this will work without eval

```
%w{user_id for_whom_id category_id product_status_id}.each do |f|
  code = <<-C
  it "should fail validation with no #{f}" do
    should_fail_on_validation { |p| p.#{f} = nil }
  end
  C
  eval code
end
```

?

Comment: "Better/best" solution questions should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see why this was closed, but I think with a little rewording it could be reopened. Perhaps if it was asking how to do this without using eval?

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
%w{user_id for_whom_id category_id product_status_id}.each do |f|
  it "should fail validation with no #{f}" do
    should_fail_on_validation { |p| p.public_send "#{f}=", nil }
  end
end
```

It's best to avoid the eval if possible. And in this case, it isn't necessary.

Comment: Given how flexible `send` and its companion methods are, you rarely need to *actually* `eval` something.